# How to separate a string column into multiple columns?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-manipulation

```r
# A tibble: 268 x 1
   `Which of these social media platforms do you have an account in right now?`
   <chr>                                                                       
 1 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Snapchat, Reddit, Signal                      
 2 Reddit                                                                      
 3 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Linkedin, Snapchat, Reddit, Quora             
 4 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Snapchat                                      
 5 Facebook, Instagram, TikTok, Snapchat                                       
 6 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Linkedin, Snapchat                            
 7 Facebook, Instagram, TikTok, Linkedin, Snapchat, Reddit                     
 8 Facebook, Instagram, Snapchat                                               
 9 Linkedin, Reddit                                                            
10 Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, TikTok                                        
# ... with 258 more rows
```

I'd like to separate this one string column into multiple columns to obtain each social media in a column of its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `unnest_tokens` from the `tidytext` package combined with `spread` from `tidyr` to get the effect you're after...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df %>%
  mutate(Id = row_number(), HasAccount = "Yes") %>%
  unnest_tokens(Network, `Which of these social media platforms do you have an account in right now?`, to_lower = F) %>%
  spread(Network, HasAccount, fill = "No")
```

(I generated my own version of your data, so this will look different from yours)

```
# A tibble: 268 x 8
      Id Facebook Instagram Reddit Signal Snapchat TikTok Twitter
   <int> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  
 1     1 No       No        No     No     No       No     Yes    
 2     2 Yes      Yes       No     No     Yes      No     Yes    
 3     3 No       Yes       No     Yes    No       Yes    No     
 4     4 No       Yes       No     No     Yes      No     No     
 5     5 No       Yes       No     Yes    Yes      Yes    Yes    
 6     6 No       Yes       No     No     No       No     No     
 7     7 No       No        Yes    Yes    No       Yes    Yes    
 8     8 No       No        Yes    No     No       No     Yes    
 9     9 No       No        Yes    No     Yes      Yes    No     
10    10 No       Yes       Yes    Yes    Yes      No     Yes
```

Comment: I received this error when executing your code ```` Erreur : Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 2 rows:
* 451, 452````

Comment: @wageeh I added a fix (the `mutate(Id = row_number())` line)

Comment: I still get this error ````Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function````

Answer (score 2):

`tidyr::separate` should do this for you (although it may warn about uneven numbers of elements in different rows)

```r
library(tidyverse)
dd <- tibble(x = c("a", "a, b", "a, b, c"))
maxcols <- 3
dd %>% separate(x, into=paste0("y", 1:maxcols))
```

```r
 y1    y2    y3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     NA    NA   
2 a     b     NA   
3 a     b     c
```

> Warning message:
> Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [1, 2].

I think @JasonPunyon's answer is more useful than mine, although mine does address your question as written ("separate this one string column into multiple columns")